# How do you add a MAC-based routing whitelist with DD-WRT and the OpenVPN client?

Tags: linux, firewall, routing, dd-wrt, iptables

I have an OpenVPN client set up on my DD-WRT home router which maintains a VPN into my workplace.

Slight problem: I don't want random lusers who access my wireless AP to have access to my company's VPN. (yes, it's secured acceptably well, but I have reason to take further steps.)

Can `iptables` be convinced to deny routing to all source MAC addresses except a select few which I specify? I tried using the `--mac-source` parameter as follows:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tap0 -j REJECT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tap0 -j ACCEPT --mac-source 00:01:02:03:04:05
```

The `REJECT` rule works, but the `ACCEPT` rule does not. (note that the `-I` parameter is being used to ensure that the `ACCEPT` rule comes before the `REJECT` rule.)

Has anyone else had experience setting up a whitelist like this?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your issue here is that MAC addresses are only a valid option for the PREROUTING and POSTROUTING tables. I did this in the following clunky fashion...

1. In prerouting table on the incoming interface from the LAN, select the MAC address of the machine you want to let through, and use DNAT to alter the IP address to one of your choosing which would not otherwise be in use.

   -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -j DNAT --  to 192.168.2.200 -m comment --comment "machine to be allowed"
2. In the FORWARD table, set a rule to accept that IP, with a policy for FORWARD otherwise to drop all traffic.

   -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.200 -j ACCEPT